# How can I remove sprites when they are outside viewport, but then add them again if I return to their location to save memory

Tags: ios, memory-efficiency, memory, spritekit, swift

I'm creating an open-world RPG like Neverwinter nights. But I’m worried about memory and am afraid if I just populate a huge world with physics based sprite nodes, I won't have any memory for anything else.

The method I thought of is to remove the sprites when they go far outside of the viewport and then re-add those sprites when I get close to their location.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Try not to worry about the problems you have not faced yet. Make a prototype and do the load-testing and see what are the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: How does your game know which sprites to spawn where in the first place?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm thinking I would have a invisible sprite node that encapsulates all others in the area and on collision, I then add those sprite nodes to predesignated points through a function

Comment: @Kromster A fair point lol

Comment: That sounds like an approach worth trying. What happens when you test the idea?

Comment: @DMGregory Going to work on that today, I haven't tried yet xd